# Federated search on D2RQ

Tags: jena, d2rq, federated-queries

I'm using D2RQ to map relational database to an RDF format. Everything works fine except when I want to do a federated search from another endpoint I'm seeing this in a log file:

> Query execution error: com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.ARQNotImplemented: OpNull

Is it possible to do a federated queries in **D2RQ** ver **0.8.1**?

Thank you

Comment: D2RQ is based on old jena (2.x), that does not fully support SPARQL 1.1 - this may be a cause of that exception. There is now [ONT-D2RQ](https://github.com/avicomp/ont-d2rq), which is for up2date jena. But: no server yet.

Comment: a simple fuseki server is added